# how to split a string into arrays using perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

There is a string as:

```
$string= 123456-9876;
```

Need to split it in array as follows:

```
$string = [12,34,56,98,76]
```

trying to split it as split('-',$string) is not serving the purpose.
How could i do that in perl?

Comment: Do you want to split it into 2-digit substrings?

Comment: Instead of splitting, match what you want to keep: `$string = [ $string =~ /(\d\d)/g ]`

Comment: how about this? `([^-].)`

Comment: What is the rule for splitting?

Answer (score 5):

Extract pairs of digits: (e.g. `"1234-5678"` ⇒ `[12,34,56,78]`)

```
$string = [ $string =~ /\d\d/g ];
```

Extract pairs of digits, even if separated by non-digits: (e.g. `"1234-567-8"` ⇒ `[12,34,56,78]`)

```
$string = [ $string =~ s/\D//rg =~ /../sg ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting, you can capture all 2 digit numbers with this perl code,

```
$str =  "123456-9876";
my @matches = $str =~ /\d{2}/g;

print "@matches\n";
```

Prints,

```
12 34 56 98 76
```

**Another solution,** that just groups two digits no matter whatever, wherever non-digits are present in the string, without mutating the original string

```
$string =  "1dd23-dsd--456-9-876";
while($string =~ /(\d).*?(\d)/g) {
        print "$1$2 ";
}
```

Prints,

```
12 34 56 98 76
```